# Automator Service to insert text only available when text is selected

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, services

I'm trying to make an Automator Service to insert the current date.  I have one that works but it is **only available in the Services menu when text is selected**.  I need it to be available *when there is no text selected*.

Here is the Automator Services script:

[image: Automator Script to insert current date]

The application I'm trying to use the service with is TextEdit.  I'm seeing the same behavior in other applications like TextMate and Pages: few or no entries in the Services menu until I select some text, then lots of Services available.

Perhaps there is some way to do this with AppleScript, like getting the text onto the clipboard and sending a "command-V" to the application.  But I would still need the AppleScript to be available in the Services menu somehow.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to show _Service Menu_ with no input. You would really be better off using a third party application. If you mostly want one for snippets like this, TextExpander would be best choice; for more versatility Keyboard Maestro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/589184/finder-not-enabling-use-of-services-when-changing-service-receives-selected-in

> OS X sometimes **ignores changes to services after they've been saved in Automator, possibly due to caching**. So if the service started out as a text service, chances are your changes aren't getting picked up. To circumvent this problem, **select File » Duplicate in Automator and save the service under a new name, and try again**. Then delete the original service from ~/Library/Services.

(Answer is by Daniel Beck)

I duplicated my Service script (in Automator) as suggested above and now it shows up in the Services menu without needing to select text.  I suspect when I first created the script that I had "Service receives text input" selected, and then I changed it later.  Note that also checking "Output replaces selected text" should not be changed after first saving the Service.